# Convertir gráfico de Google Charts en Responsive

Tags: html5, responsive, chart.js, charts, gráficas

Cordial saludo

Por favor, quisiera agregar a estas gráficas de Google charts la propiedad de ser Responsive, este sería el código actual:
Este código muestra las graficas pero sin la propiedad de ser adaptable de acuerdo al dispositivo.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Element", "Cantidad", { role: "style" } ],
    ["Documentos", <?php echo $doc;?>, "#E7EE23"],
    ["Presentaciones", <?php echo $pres;?>, "#4AD3CE"],
    ["Vídeos", <?php echo $vi;?>, "#5DADDA"],
    ["Audios", <?php echo $aud;?>, "#FAA423"],
    ["Obras literarias", <?php echo $obrl;?>, "color: pink"]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
                   { calc: "stringify",
                     sourceColumn: 1,
                     type: "string",
                     role: "annotation" },
                   2]);

  var options = {
    title: "¿Qué tienes para mi Discover? - Última actualización: <?php echo $fecha;?>",
    width: 980,
    height: 400,
    bar: {groupWidth: "100%"},
    legend: { position: "none" },
  };
  var chart = new 
  google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
</script>
```

Este muestra las graficas:

```
  <p align="center">
  <div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 1000px; height: 300px;" align="center"></div>
  </p>
 
  <p align="center">
  <div id="columnchart_values2" style="width: 1000px; height: 300px;" align="center"></div>';
  </p>
```

Comment: Por favor, si te funciono la repuesta recuerda "ACEPTAR" para que otros Usuarios se beneficien de ella.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día Ivan

Para solventar tu problema tenemos que hacer varias cosas, primero quitar el ancho y alto en la clase del `<div>`, luego debes agregar en el `<option>` el atributo chartArea, con el ancho en porcentaje y luego, para que se redibuje cuando cambien el tamaño de la ventana, una pequeña funcion en JS que vuelva a pintar la gráfica.

Aquí el codigo (te deje tus datos), espero que cumpla tus expectativas:

```
<p align="center">
<div id="columnchart_values" align="center"></div>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("current", {
        packages: ['corechart']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ["Element", "Cantidad", {
                role: "style"
            }],
            ["Documentos", <?php echo $doc; ?>, "#E7EE23"],
            ["Presentaciones", <?php echo $pres; ?>, "#4AD3CE"],
            ["Vídeos", <?php echo $vi; ?>, "#5DADDA"],
            ["Audios", <?php echo $aud; ?>, "#FAA423"],
            ["Obras literarias", <?php echo $obrl; ?>, "color: pink"]
        ]);

        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0, 1,
            {
                calc: "stringify",
                sourceColumn: 1,
                type: "string",
                role: "annotation"
            },
            2
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: "¿Qué tienes para mi Discover? - Última actualización: <?php echo $fecha; ?>",
            width: 980,
            height: 400,
            chartArea: {
                'width': '70%'
            },
            bar: {
                groupWidth: "100%"
            },
            legend: {
                position: "none"
            },
        };
        var chart = new
        google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
        chart.draw(view, options);
    }

    window.onresize = RedibujarGrafica;

    function RedibujarGrafica() {
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    };
</script>
```